# Facebook Share Og Error

Tags: php, facebook, debugging, share

I have a `header.php` file for all pages except `index.php` and I used base href tag to avoid any error (not loading css,javascript bla bla...),
Now, I call [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) og codes according to the `$_GET` value I get but [facebook](/questions/tagged/facebook) share debugger shows index file because of base href tag.

How can I solve this problem. ?

Comment: Specify the correct URL via the `og:url` meta tag.

Comment: Thx dude, it is work :)